# Using more 5GHz channels for an access point on my Intel WiFi card

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I am trying to use different 5GHz channels but I cannot seem to be able to use them. For example, I set `channel=120` in my `hostapd.conf` and when I run it I get:

```
Channel 120 (primary) not allowed for AP mode, flags: 0x3e0797b NO-IR RADAR
wlp0s20f3: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (120) not found from the channel list of current mode (2) IEEE 802.11a
wlp0s20f3: IEEE 802.11 Hardware does not support configured channel
Could not select hw_mode and channel. (-3)
```

Looking at output of `iw list` I see:

```
        Frequencies:
            * 5180 MHz [36] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (22.0 dBm)
```

Sure, it says `no IR` for channel 120, so it cannot use it. But when I do `iw reg get` I get:

```
global
country US: DFS-FCC
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

This looks like I should be able to use it based on my regulatory domain (US) which seems to be correctly configured. So my question is, why I cannot use all channels my regulatory domain is allowing me and how do I configure things so that I can?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Information from `dmesg` about my WiFi card:

```
[ 1212.667202] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[ 1212.667345] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[ 1212.672301] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[ 1212.672301] Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation
[ 1212.674819] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[ 1212.674820] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[ 1212.674998] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[ 1212.688262] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[ 1212.696142] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[ 1212.696660] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[ 1212.737889] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: d0:c6:37:xx:xx:xx
[ 1212.805437] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[ 1212.808951] thermal thermal_zone4: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[ 1212.809468] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

In the US, channels 120-128 have special restrictions because of Terminal Doppler Weather Radar (TDWR) used at some airports. Even though the rules for those channels mostly affect professionals doing outdoor installations within proximity of the few airports that use TDWR on these frequencies, some Wi-Fi equipment vendors choose not to do the regulatory compliance certification work required for supporting those channels in AP mode.

See if you can use a channel (and width) that doesn't overlap with those channels in the 120's.

[image]

Comment: Those same regulations required router manufacturers to bake the region they were sold in, making it impossible, to change the region so out of band channels could be used.  Most governments have similar policies.

Comment: OK, but `iw list` shows also channel like 52 with `no IR`. Why I cannot use that one?

Comment: The problems that Wi-Fi router can cause are not as small as your description implies. Comments under [this Hack-a-day blog post](https://hackaday.com/2015/08/31/fcc-introduces-rules-banning-wifi-router-firmware-modification/): "*You would be surprised how much interference a single WLAN basestation operating on the wrong frequency causes to a weather radar.*" and also "*in the observatory? Yes. We routinely (approx. once per month) have to run around in our tracking van pinpointing 5GHz WISP sources, often miles away (by LOS, not driving)*"